# Running Fortran OpenMP codes with OpenMP Tools interface

Tags: fortran, openmp

I'm trying to run a simple Fortran OpenMP code with a library using the OpenMP Tools Interface (OMPT).

I have this working with a C++ code using clang + llvm openmp runtime, just by doing `OMP_TOOL_LIBRARIES=/home/path/to/libotter.so ./openmp_program`

I tried to do the same with flang/f18, but they seem to use gcc as a compiler underneath, which then links to libgomp, which as far as I can tell doesn't support OMPT. I also tried the intel compiler, but I couldn't build the library with intel's 2021.1.1 oneAPI release, as there was no "ompt.h" header.

Is there a way to point a Fortran compiler to a specific OpenMP runtime - or is there a Fortram & C/C++ compiler toolchain that supports the OpenMP Tools interface? None of these three appear to and I don't know of any others.

Comment: A similar question was posted [here](https://forum.openmp.org/viewtopic.php?t=1950). I hope this helps you.